# neighbouring pixels : next smaller and bigger perimeter

Tags: image-processing

I have a list of pixels centers, for example :

```
perimeter = {{56.5, 68.5}, {56.5, 69.5}, {57.5, 65.5}, {57.5, 66.5}, {57.5, 
  67.5}, {57.5, 70.5}, {57.5, 71.5}, {58.5, 65.5}, {58.5, 
  71.5}, {59.5, 64.5}, {59.5, 71.5}, {60.5, 64.5}, {60.5, 
  72.5}, {61.5, 64.5}, {61.5, 73.5}, {62.5, 64.5}, {62.5, 
  74.5}, {63.5, 64.5}, {63.5, 65.5}, {63.5, 74.5}, {64.5, 
  65.5}, {64.5, 73.5}, {65.5, 66.5}, {65.5, 73.5}, {66.5, 
  67.5}, {66.5, 72.5}, {66.5, 73.5}, {67.5, 68.5}, {67.5, 
  69.5}, {67.5, 70.5}, {67.5, 71.5}, {67.5, 72.5}}
```

which forms a closed path as we can visually see by doing :

```
img = Image[Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {i, 100}, {j, 100}]];
HighlightImage[img, {AbsolutePointSize[5], perimeter}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Question** : do you know how to efficiently **find the list of neighbouring pixels that form the next bigger (blue) and smaller(yellow) perimeter** as shown in this picture :[image]

The notion of next smaller and next bigger being kind of approximate here as long as it preserves the general shape of the initial perimeter, for example a smaller perimeter  like this (purple dots are added) is also acceptable to me :[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `perimeter` be the list of points provided in the question. Start by creating a mask of the region:

```
mask = HighlightImage[
   ConstantImage[Black, {100, 100}],
   {White, Polygon[perimeter]}
   ];
mask
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Enlarge the mask using `Dilation`:

```
Dilation[mask, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Make the mask smaller using `Erosion`:

```
Erosion[mask, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Convert the region back into a perimeter using `MorphologicalPerimeter`:

```
mperimeter = MorphologicalPerimeter[mask]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Get the pixel positions of the perimeter using `PixelValuePositions`:

```
PixelValuePositions[mperimeter, 1]

(* Out:
   {{63, 75}, {64, 75}, {62, 74}, {63, 74}, {64, 74}, {65, 74}, {66, 
  74}, {67, 74}, {61, 73}, {62, 73}, {67, 73}, {68, 73}, {58, 
  72}, {59, 72}, {60, 72}, {61, 72}, {68, 72}, {58, 71}, {68, 
  71}, {57, 70}, {58, 70}, {68, 70}, {57, 69}, {67, 69}, {68, 
  69}, {57, 68}, {66, 68}, {67, 68}, {57, 67}, {65, 67}, {66, 
  67}, {57, 66}, {58, 66}, {59, 66}, {64, 66}, {65, 66}, {59, 
  65}, {60, 65}, {61, 65}, {62, 65}, {63, 65}, {64, 65}} *)
```

As you note, "next bigger" and "next smaller" are not unambiguously defined. This approach let's you choose what you want to do by allowing you to set the kernel in `Dilation` and `Erosion`, and `CornerNeighbors` in `MorphologicalPerimeter`.

You can also choose between `ImageValuePosition` and `PixelValuePositions`.

I want to note that if you want to go back and forth between perimeter pixels and mask images without changing the size of the region in doing so, you may need to use `EdgeForm[None]`:

```
pixels = PixelValuePositions[mperimeter, 1];
mask = HighlightImage[
   ConstantImage[Black, {100, 100}],
   {White, EdgeForm[None], Polygon[pixels]}
   ];
PixelValuePositions[MorphologicalPerimeter[mask], 1]
(* Output is the same as the input, pixels *)
```

However, it appears that on the list supplied to the question, `EdgeForm[None]` should *not* be used. It works anyway, and indeed does not work with `EdgeForm[None]`. It's unclear to me how this difference comes about.